# Proper way to throw an error in a TPL Task so VS2012 does not complain

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2012, task-parallel-library

I have founds threads similar but not the same so forgive me if it turns out to be a duplicate.  How does one properly "throw" an error inside a task.  I have this code and when the conditions are right it will throw the error but Visual Studio complains that it is unhanded.  But afterwards everything performs as it should including the _LoadDataMappingFieldListError method.  I thought the first ContinueWith would suffice but it seems not.  Do I need to actually create 2 separate tasks - one for the test and then another for the actual retrieval? Seems a little redundant.  Here is the code:

```
........
if (dcMapping.SettingsComplete().IsNullEmpty())
{
    _TaskCanceller = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
    _TaskLoader = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //Set the indicator and first test the connection to make sure it is working
        IsLoadingDataMappingFieldList = true;

        string test = dcMapping.TestConnection();
        if (test.IsNotNullEmpty())
            throw new DataConnectionException(test);  // <--THE THROW IN QUESTION
        return dcMapping.GetFieldNameList();          // <--VS BREAKS HERE SAYING THE ABOVE IS UNHANDLED
    });

    //If there is an error
    _TaskLoader.ContinueWith(
        antecendant => _LoadDataMappingFieldListError(antecendant.Exception),
        _TaskCanceller.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    //Set up receiving function
    _TaskLoader.ContinueWith(
        antecendant => _LoadDataMappingFieldListComplete((List<string>)antecendant.Result, RemapFields),
        _TaskCanceller.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have the option "Just my code" turned on.  In that case, it is indicating that the exception *is* unhandled with respect to "just your code".  The exception is caught by framework code and stored in the `Task`.

I, personally, would recommend turning off the "Just my code" setting as it tends to get in the way more than it helps.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Interesting, never noticed that option before.  Seems that was disabled by default in VS2010.  I just upgraded to 2012 (finally) which explains the difference I suppose.